# How to get rid of warning about missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to create compontentDidMount effect using useEffect. When I always want to do this, I just pass empty array as second argument. Now I have a warning about missing dependency, but I don't want passing it. I need that the value change just when component is mounting.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    const TempValues = {};
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
        TempValues[param[0]] = +param[1];
    }
    setValues(TempValues);
}, [])
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if the probs changed, the component will be re-rendered anyway. So why use `useEffect` here at all? `useState` like: `const [values] = useState(Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(location.search).entries()));` would yield the same result. And if you're worried about re-executing that code-snippet, you could use an initializer function to `useState`.

Comment: I have o component which is usign data from props.location.search. When I click on the button on page I want to load other component using routing. When I do this I loss data in my first component- and i don't whant to lose them

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Where do you lose data?

Comment: when location.search is changing. When I change Route I want to display other component and don't  disapearing first where I don't want lose data here

Comment: If you use the snippet I mentioned in my first comment, `values` will only contain data from the first render. If later the probs change, `values` will not (as long as the component stays mounted). And you still have access to the *live* probs, which you can pass to other components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind, **linter is not dumb and it's always looking to prevent any further unknown errors that you may not notice at the moment**. So it is not wise to get rid of this kind of errors with the special comments like:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

In the first place, **you should always look for unchanged values in your code**, in your particular case, it could be `props.location.search` or `setValues` since we do not know how do you working with `props.location.search` in your other parts of code (or the URI itself) so it's better to use `setValues` and `props.location` combination instead.

So it should be something like this:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    const TempValues = {};
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
        TempValues[param[0]] = +param[1];
    }
    setValues(TempValues);
}, [setValues, props.location])
```

But in any case, if you do not care about this stuff, you can use the *eslint exhaustive-deps* comment to make this work as you wanted.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(props.location.search);
    const TempValues = {};
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
        TempValues[param[0]] = +param[1];
    }
    setValues(TempValues);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```

**NOTE:** Keep in mind warnings will be ignored in production builds.

### UPDATE

Since you got a special and you want to keep your data when the routes got changes to make a `useRef` instead to avoid using props.location.search directly. So by this approach, we will keep an eye on `props.location` change with the first `useEffect` and then we can freely use the updated version of `props.location` in other `useEffect` with accessing the other properties within it without any concern, so it won't restart with anything since we got no dependencies.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({})

const location = useRef(props.location);
useEffect(() => {
  location.current = location;
}, [location]);

useEffect(() => {
    const query = new URLSearchParams(location.current.search);
    const TempValues = {};
    for (let param of query.entries()) {
        TempValues[param[0]] = +param[1];
    }
    setValues(TempValues);
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use
`// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`
just below the setValues(TempValues); statement.
It's not a very advisable thing to do.
You should add props.location.search in the dependency array.

Comment: But what if I want to changing values just in first mounting? When I add this to dependency it will always change when props.location.search will change

Comment: That's why disabling the warning is an explicit action. Check to see if it does not cause any stale data problems. Everything else is fine.

Comment: So doing it in this case will be completely correct?

Comment: For suppose your query params change like from
?q=1 to ?q=2.
you'd ideally want to read 2 in your effect.
Think of it like didMount and DidUpdate combined.

Comment: exactly i have for example ?q=1, and after time i have a route displaying next component, and path is changing, but I don't want to change early component

Comment: If the entire path is changing you don't need to worry. It'll automatically unmount
if only the query param change somehow and the component rendered will remain the same.